# node js TypeError: callBack is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here two functions

```
function pushArray(data, array){
    var index = -1;
    array.forEach(function(item) { 
        if(item.name === data.name) { 
            index = array.indexOf(item);
            console.log('found existing item at ' + index);
        }
    });
    if(index >= 0){
        array[index] = newItem;
    }else {
        array.push(newItem);        
    }
}

function showData(data, array){
    try {
        if(data){
            console.log('data \n');
            console.log(data.toString());
            console.log(array);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Showing data caused error: " + error);
    }
}
```

This is how the callbacks are called

```
fsReadFile(csvPath1, pushArray. array1);
fsReadFile(csvPath1, showData, array1);

function fsReadFile (filePath, callBack, array) {
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        callBack(data, array);
    });
}
```

the show data shows either data and array when send as callback but the pushArray doesn't work as callback as node js complains

```
    array.forEach(function(item) {
         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

Is that more an callback or array issue ? If anyone could explain the root cause ?

Comment: Nowhere in this code do you use `pushArray` (as a callback or otherwise). We have no way of telling why the second argument to it is not an object with a `forEach` property.

Comment: How do you call pushArray?

Comment: added some calling code. Again the show Data works with that

Comment: @user3732793 — The "calling code" still doesn't mention the pushArray function.

Comment: You need a real [MCVE]

Comment: added now some more code but there is honestly not much different in how these two functions are called..thought

Comment: @user3732793 — There are two significant differences, each of which would break it individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> fsReadFile(csvPath1, pushArray(). array1);
> ```

You are calling `pushArray` **immediately**, with no arguments (so `array` is `undefined`), and the return value is passed as the second argument. **Don't call it there**.

Then you have a typo where you have a `.` instead of a comma (so you try to read the `array1` property of the return value of `pushArray()` and don't pass a third argument at all).

```
fsReadFile(csvPath1, pushArray, array1);
```

Comment: oh man ...you are absolutely right there is a typo...notepad is probably not a good editor....